# int x=1000 and just x=1000 yield different values

Tags: c++, variables

I was learning global and local variables and suddenly while experimenting in the IDE, I noticed something like this :

The following program yields 100 500 1000 (in three diff lines)-

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int X=100;
void printing ()
{
    cout<<X<<"\n";
    int X=500;
    cout<<X<<"\n";
}
int main ()
{
    int X=1000;
    printing ();

    cout<<X<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the following program yields 1000 500 1000 (in three diff lines)-

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int X=100;
void printing ()
{
    cout<<X<<"\n";
    int X=500;
    cout<<X<<"\n";
}
int main ()
{
    X=1000;
    printing ();

    cout<<X<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the first code, I have written `int X = 1000` as the opening line of the main function and in the second code, I have written `X = 1000` as the opening line. Why is that creating a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first program, you declare another variable called `X` using the syntax `int X = 1000` which **shadows** your global variable. Since your `printing()` function doesn't see this new variable, it access your global `X` and prints it.

In your second program, you assign a new value to the global `X` which can now be happily accessed by your `printing` function.

For more information, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing